# Winform controls and Threads

Tags: c#, winforms

I have read that you cannot manipulate a control that is in a different thread.

I have two controls that use the same Singleton class.  These two controls are in different threads which is why I am using the singleton to communicate between them.

My question is:
Is it just Winforms stuff that cannot be manipulated across threads?  Can I pass data via the Singleton every time without fail or do I have to do that some other way?

EDIT:

Due to the comments I'm getting, I'd better clarify that I'm not looking for how to do it, but when I need to do it and when I don't.

Comment: "These two controls are in different threads" ... let's start here.  You shouldn't have controls on separate threads.  UI components should only exist on one thread: the main UI thread.  If you want to manipulate the controls -- on the main thread -- from a separate thread, you do so through the controls' `Invoke` methods.  This will safely schedule the action to be performed on the control when the event loop gets around to it.

Comment: I don't control how these controls are implemented, they are seperate add-ins to a CRM framework and that's how they get done.  I'm aware of the invoke stuff, my question is more when I need to use it and when I don't in this scenario.

Comment: @Graham You don't need to control how they're implemented.  Create them on the one UI thread, and only ever access them or manipulate them from the UI thread.

Comment: "When you need to use it"  what is the "it" you are referring to?  how do you know the library is using separate threads for its controls?  That doesn't make sense.  It would be *your* code that uses the controls and does so on this or that thread.  And I'm saying only do it from the UI thread.

Comment: You *can't* create controls from different threads, not without some very advanced code using AppDomains and message pump initialization. .NET has classes that make asynchronous programming a *lot* easier, eg `async/await`, the `IProgress<T>` class, asynchronous binding to data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Creating controls in other threads is easy.  You just call the constructor.  The problem is that you then can only use them from that thread, which, if it isn't your UI thread, means they can't interact with your existing UI.  It also makes the code a mess if you actually try to do it, as you would then have multiple UI thread.

Comment: @Servy *something* needs to start a new message pump. This needs a call to `Application.Run` at least, not an AppDomain. I never did such a thing though because there is no point - it's not the UI that causes performance problems. Loading too much data, running long jobs on the UI thread etc are the real problems

Comment: @Graham you never need to do it be cause you don't need to create controls in different threads. What are you trying to do? BTW, sending a message from one control to the other doesn't need any singletons. That's what `Progress<T>` is about, as [explained here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can create a control without having a message pump.  You can write `new Label();` in a background thread without having a message pump.  It won't do you much good, but you *can*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Winforms controls just belong to the very large set of .NET Framework classes that are not thread-safe.  Something as basic as a `List<T>` is not thread-safe.  There is something you do about it in the cast of List, you can use the `lock` keyword to ensure that only one thread ever accesses the members at the same time.

But that cannot work for Winforms controls, you cannot inject a `lock` in the operating system code that also accesses the control.  So rock-hard requirement that your code always runs on the same thread that created the control.  It is the very reason that `Application.Run()` exists, it is the universal solution to the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  Where multiple threads in the operating system and other processes produce and your single UI thread consumes, thus keeping the UI objects thread-safe.

It is technically possible to have more than one UI thread, each having their own top-level window (Form, not a child control).  That however is a pretty risky scenario as well, the SystemEvents.ThemeChanged event is a major trouble-maker.  Lots of controls in the toolbox subscribe that event, they use it to redraw themselves when the active Windows theme changes.  This event is raised on a single thread, normally the first UI thread you created.

Which implies that the controls on the second thread are going to get this event on the wrong thread.  Which is very apt to cause deadlock.  Very commonly when the workstation is locked (Win+L key), switching to the secure desktop and back triggers the ThemeChanged event.  Excessively ugly to debug, looks [like this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/), and next to impossible to fix.  If you do this then you are pretty much forced to create your own control classes and not use the toolbox.

"Don't do it" is the only good advice, it is never necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a thread, where you want to modify your control, you should call `BeginInvoke` method of your control. For example:

```
Task.Run(() => 
{
    label1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
    {
        label1.Text = "Something";
    }));
})
```

Comment: If you can use `Task.Run` you can also use `async/await` and *not* have to use delegates. It's also better to use the `IProgress<T>` interface to report progress across threads without hard-coding controls into background code